# Mocking in Python for Unit tests seems not working

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing a unit test in Python for the first time.

I want to write a unit test for my service function.
The structure of the file `service.py` is:

```py
class A
  function A1
  function A2
class B
  function B1
  function B2
```

I want to write a unit test for `function A1`. It uses `session_factory` object which is declared in another module called `db.py`. And `db.py` module is in `config` package.

I am using python 3.9. This object also depends on some other objects.
This is the file `db.py`:

```py
class DatabaseSettings(BaseSettings):
    username: str
    password: str
    name: str
    host: str
    sql_echo: bool = False
    
    class Config(abc.Config):
        env_prefix = f"{abc.Config.env_prefix}DB_"
    
    def url(self):
        return f"mysql+aiomysql://{self.username}:{self.password}@{self.host}/{self.name}"
    
    
config = DatabaseSettings()
    
engine = create_async_engine(config.url(), echo=config.sql_echo)
session_factory = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)
```

Here's my call to service function from the unit test and patching the object:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
@patch("config.db.session_factory")
async def test_result():
    await service.classA.A1();
```

The mock does not seem to be working. It's trying to create config object which looks for the db properties and throwing `field required (type=value_error.missing)` exception.
My idea is if the `session_factory` is mocked, it should not look for `config`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You use `@patch(config.db.session_factory)` this means that you are trying to patch the object `session_factory`. Are you sure? Is this your intention? Or you want to patch() `sessionmaker()`. An other possible problem is the name of the file `config.db.py`. On my opinion is better remove the point between `config` and `db`.

Comment: I am trying to patch the `session_factory` object as this is used in my service function. I want to mock the behavior of `get()`(fetches data from db) method of this `session_factory`.

Comment: `config` is the package and `db.py` is the module.

Comment: I think you have to modify `@patch("config.db.session_factory")` to `@patch("config.db.sessionmaker", return_value=<something>)` and this is assigned to `session_factory` when you execute `test_result()`